# Split or separate an object of class "character"

Tags: r

I want to create a data frame with the elements inside an object of class "character".

```
9 15 22 23 0 1,052 393 

10 16 23 0 1 1,652 291

11 17 0 1 2 1,593 228 

12 18 1 2 3 1,097 170
```

I have been trying to separate all this info into 7 columns but with no success.

Here is the code I have used:

```
download.file("https://www.asx.com.au/documents/products/asx-24-market-dynamics-mar-18.pdf", "asx-24-market-dynamics-mar-18.pdf", mode = "wb")

#install.packages("pdftools")
library(pdftools)
txt <- pdf_text("asx-24-market-dynamics-mar-18.pdf") 

# get second page text 
page_2 <- txt[2]

# separate lines 
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
page_2a <- page_2 %>% 
                 str_split(pattern = "\n") %>%
                 unlist()

# create "two tables"
tbl1 <- page_2a[6:29]

tbl2 <- page_2a[33:56]

 # transform into a data frame
 tbl1 <- ?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(pdftools); library(tidyverse)
```

Now you have two character vectors with whitespace as separators, so use `read.table` and pass to the `text` parameter:

```
head( read.table( text=tbl1 ) ) 
#---------
V1 V2 V3 V4 V5    V6  V7    V8    V9 V10    V11   V12 V13
1  9 15 22 23  0 1,052 393 6,119 8,176  14 10,196 1,279 646
2 10 16 23  0  1 1,652 291 5,222 7,325  11 10,126 1,053 600
3 11 17  0  1  2 1,593 228 4,750 6,917  13  9,754   923 617
4 12 18  1  2  3 1,097 170 4,193 4,801  12  9,937   910 549
5 13 19  2  3  4   644 624 1,733 2,605  12 10,259   851 512
6 14 20  3  4  5   658 103 1,910 2,081  11 10,070   808 421
```

Since you seem to be new at this, I'd suggest being very suspicious when you see commas in what appear to be numeric values. R does not use commas as thousands-separators, so columns: V6, V8, V9, V11, and V12 at the very least are now factor columns. (Also holds true for V13 as shown by `str`)

```
 str( read.table( text=tbl1 ) )
'data.frame':   24 obs. of  13 variables:
 $ V1 : int  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 ...
 $ V2 : int  15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 0 ...
 $ V3 : int  22 23 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 ...
 $ V4 : int  23 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 ...
 $ V5 : int  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
 $ V6 : Factor w/ 24 levels "1,052","1,097",..: 1 5 4 2 16 17 21 20 24 3 ...
 $ V7 : Factor w/ 24 levels "1,324","1,593",..: 19 15 13 7 22 4 21 20 3 9 ...
 $ V8 : Factor w/ 24 levels "1,323","1,733",..: 24 22 21 18 2 3 11 1 4 6 ...
 $ V9 : Factor w/ 24 levels "1,222","10,959",..: 22 21 19 12 9 7 8 1 16 18 ...
 $ V10: int  14 11 13 12 12 11 9 10 0 13 ...
 $ V11: Factor w/ 24 levels "10,070","10,119",..: 5 3 21 22 7 1 19 20 23 6 ...
 $ V12: Factor w/ 24 levels "1,053","1,212",..: 4 1 24 23 22 19 20 21 10 11 ...
 $ V13: Factor w/ 24 levels "1,009","1,019",..: 16 14 15 12 11 10 9 8 13 17 ...
```

You can fix most but not all of those columns with `gsub`:

```
str( read.table( text=gsub(",","",tbl1) ) )
'data.frame':   24 obs. of  13 variables:
 $ V1 : int  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 ...
 $ V2 : int  15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 0 ...
 $ V3 : int  22 23 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 ...
 $ V4 : int  23 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 ...
 $ V5 : int  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
 $ V6 : Factor w/ 24 levels "1052","1097",..: 1 5 4 2 14 16 21 20 24 3 ...
 $ V7 : int  393 291 228 170 624 103 525 44 1690 2308 ...
 $ V8 : int  6119 5222 4750 4193 1733 1910 2116 1323 10606 12539 ...
 $ V9 : int  8176 7325 6917 4801 2605 2081 2486 1222 5319 6119 ...
 $ V10: int  14 11 13 12 12 11 9 10 0 13 ...
 $ V11: int  10196 10126 9754 9937 10259 10070 9465 9606 9960 10239 ...
 $ V12: int  1279 1053 923 910 851 808 839 843 1714 1874 ...
 $ V13: int  646 600 617 549 512 421 316 297 585 688 ...

table(read.table( text=gsub(",","",tbl1) )[6])

  1052   1097   1368   1593   1652   3323   3773   4054   4243   4648    565    599    608    644   6573    658    684   6966 
     1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1 
   782    814    823    863    875 Closed 
     1      1      1      1      1      1
```

Answer (score 0):

We can start by making a common pattern then using `separate` to produce the desired output

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
data$A <- str_replace(data$A, ",","")      

data %>% 
    separate(A, c("a1", "a2", "a3", "a4","a5", "a6","a7", "a8"), " ")
```

**Data**

```
 data <- read.table(text = "A
                    '9 15 22 23 0 1,052 393'
                    '10 16 23 0 1 1,652 291'
                             ",header=T)
```

**Update**

```
tbl1 <- str_replace(tbl1, "\r","")       #replace \r at the end of line with ""
tbl1 <- trimws(tbl1,which = c("left"))   #trim the white space where line start
tbl1 <- gsub("[[:blank:]]+", ":", tbl1)  #replace any number of space with :
test_tbl1 <- data.frame(tbl1)             

tbl1_final <- test_tbl1 %>% 
              separate(tbl1, c("Chicago*","London*","HK/Sing","Tokyo","Aust\n(AEST)","ASX\nSPI 20\U2122","90 Day","3 Year","10 Year","ASX\nSPI 200\U2122"
               ,"90 Day","3 Year","10 Year"), ":")
```

Comment: Thanks. But what if I have chr [1:1000]? Or higher than 1000. Is there any other method so I can avoid manually inputting numbers into read.table(text = " .....")?

Comment: I just used `read.table` for **reproducibility**, i.e. to get data into R -since you did not provide data using `dput`- that I can work with it. But, you should already have this data available at your work session and you do not need to use `read.table`.

Comment: I am trying to extract the data from page 2 of this pdf  asx.com.au/documents/products/asx-24-market-dynamics-mar-18.pdf

Comment: I am getting the following: Error in UseMethod("separate_") : 
  no applicable method for 'separate_' applied to an object of class "character"

Comment: Because it is a character vector. I managed to download the file with the required package, So now we are on the same page. Do `tbl1_test <- str_replace(tbl1, "\r","")` then `test <- data.frame(tbl1_test)`. The problem now there is no equal space between columns so we can pass it to `separate`

Comment: One more question. My tbl2 <- page_2a[33:56]  has some number with decimals.  What should i change in the code in this case to have every number in its column?
    9 15 22 23 0 1.0 1.0 0.5 0.5 1 64 42 10

Comment: Just change any `tbl1` in the code to `tbl2` and it should works

Comment: One last thing, all these coulmns are `character` class so you will need to change them to `numeric` class when needed before any future data analysis.